# Hide Column conditionally in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have data like below:

```
**Account Name****Total****Remarks**
Account01         100      Remarks1
Account01         100      Remarks2
Account02          30      Remarks3
Account02          30      Remarks1
Account02          30      Remarks2
Account02          60      Remarks3
Account03          50      Remarks1
Account04          50      Remarks2
```

How can I create a formula so the result shows as below:

```
**Account Name****Total****Remarks**
Account01         100      Remarks1
Account02          30      Remarks2
Account02          60      Remarks3
Account03          50
Account04          50
```

Comment: What is the criteria?

Comment: Hi Haringer,
What criteri do You mean?

Comment: It seems you are removing some repeated data. But it is not the repetition of the full row, right? It seems something more complex.

Comment: Hi Heringer,
Yes, You are right. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the result shows two parallel blocks of data.

The left block contains the distinct pairs of account name and total.

The right block contains the distinct remarks.

If this is what you want (which is akward, but if this is your business rule...), here is how to get it in Crystal Reports:

1. Suppress the details section.
2. In the report header section, put two subreports side-by-side and do their layouts as follows.
3. In the left subreport, create a group by "account name" and a group by "total".
4. In the group-by-total header section, put the fields "account name" and "total". Do not use the details section - suppress it. Do not summarize total, just put it there.
5. In the right subreport, create a group by "remarks".
6. In the group-by-remarks header section, put the field "remarks". Do not use the details section - suppress it.